# Changing Text Label and Color By Clicking a Button

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, colors

I have this problem, I want to set a timer like this when I click on the button in my program:

The first text label `"Not Connected"` (**color red**) changes to `"Verifying"` (**color green**) and after a while it changes permenatly to `"Connected"` (**color green**)

How Do I do that ???

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't supply the code with the timer to understand what are you trying to do I can't give a better answer, you can adapt this code that I did:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Enum State
    NotConnected = 141 ' Red
    Verifying = 53 ' DarkGreen
    Connected = 79 ' Green
End Enum

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
Handles Button1.Click

    Select Case Label1.Tag

        Case Nothing
            SetLabelState(Label1, "Not Connected ", State.NotConnected)

        Case State.NotConnected
            SetLabelState(Label1, "Verifying", State.Verifying)

        Case State.Verifying
            SetLabelState(Label1, "Connected", State.Connected)

        Case State.Connected
            ' Do nothing here

        Case Else
            Throw New Exception("Select case is out of index")

    End Select

End Sub

Private Sub SetLabelState(ByVal lbl As Label, _
                          ByVal txt As String, _
                          ByVal col As State)

    lbl.BackColor = Color.FromKnownColor(CType(col, KnownColor))
    lbl.Tag = col
    lbl.Text = txt

End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Timer` class here.
Here what I have implemented in my code->

```
    //click event on the button to change the color of the label
    public void buttonColor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Timer timer = new Timer();
                timer.Interval = 500;// Timer with 500 milliseconds
                timer.Enabled = false;

                timer.Start();

                timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
            }

           void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //label text changes from 'Not Connected' to 'Verifying'
            if (labelFirst.BackColor == Color.Red)
            {
                labelFirst.BackColor = Color.Green;
                labelFirst.Text = "Verifying";
            }

            //label text changes from 'Verifying' to 'Connected'
            else if (labelFirst.BackColor == Color.Green)
            {
                labelFirst.BackColor = Color.Green;
                labelFirst.Text = "Connected";
            }

            //initial Condition (will execute)
            else
            {
                labelFirst.BackColor = Color.Red;
                labelFirst.Text = "Not Connected";
            }
        }
```